Unconditional sampling probability (without replacement)
On sampling without replacement:

Suppose that 40% of 5000 voters favor candidate Jones. A random sample
of $n=10$ voters will be selected. For the first person selected, the
probability of favoring Jones  is 0.4. In Exercise 3.35 you will show
that unconditionally the probability that the second person favors
Jones is also .4. (Chapter 3, Mathematical Statistics,Wackerly)

I was able to generalize this. For $N$ voters, let $m$ favor Jones, and $f$ not favor. The unconditional probability of the 2nd person favoring Jones is the sum of the conditional probabilities over all possible events:
$$\frac{m}{n}\cdot \frac{m-1}{n-1}+\frac{f}{n}\cdot \frac{m}{n-1}=\frac{m(m-1+f)}{n(n-1)}=\frac{m(n-1)}{n(n-1)}=\frac{m}{n}$$
(where we used $m+f=N$)
A longer calculation shows that this holds for the 3rd trial. However, I think it holds in general. But I am not able to prove it in general.
Please help.

Here's a counting argument. To compute the probability that the $k$th voter favors Jones, you need to sample without replacement $k$ times from your population of $N$ voters, and compare the number of "favorable" combinations to the number of possible combinations. There are
$$\underbrace{N\cdot (N-1)\cdot\cdots\cdot(N-[k-1])}_{\text{$k$ factors}}\tag1$$ ways to sample $k$ voters without constraint, since you select your first voter from all $N$ available voters, your second from the $N-1$ remaining, and so on. Now count the number of ways to do this with the constraint that voter #$k$ favors Jones. There are $m$ possible voters to put into slot $k$, and you select the preceding $k-1$ voters from the $N-1$ remaining voters (since you've taken one voter out to fill slot $k$). The number of ways to do this is therefore
$$
m\cdot\underbrace{ (N-1)\cdot(N-2)\cdot \cdots\cdot(N-[k-1])}_{\text{$k-1$ factors}}\tag2
$$The desired probability is the ratio $(2)/(1)$, which equals $\frac mN$.
A more direct argument uses symmetry. Pick a specific voter and imagine where she appears in the sequence of all voters selected at random with replacement (imagine arranging all $N$ voters in a line). There is no reason why this voter should appear earlier or later in the sequence, so the probability that she is placed in position $k$ is $\frac1N$. The probability that a Jones voter appears in position $k$ is $m$ times this number, since we can apply this argument to each of the $m$ voters who favor Jones. So the desired probability is $\frac mN$.
An invariance argument observes that you're still sampling at random with replacement if you take the additional step of swapping the sampled voter in position $1$ with the sampled voter in position $k$. Hence the desired probabilty $\frac mN$ follows immediately.

Proof by induction.
Base case $(k=1)$:
The probability that the first person selected favors Jones is clearly $\frac{m}{N}$.
Inductive hypothesis:
Assume for any selection $k \leqslant n$, the unconditional probability the $k$-th person favors Jones is $\frac{m}{N}$.
Inductive step $(k=n+1)$:
We consider the $(n+1)$-th person. When selecting the $(n+1)$-th person, the outcome of the previous $n$ selections affects how many Jones supporters are left in the pool. The first $n$ selections can have $x$ Jones supporters selected, where $0\leqslant x\leqslant n$; as well as $n-x$ Jones non-supporters.
For each possible number $x$ of Jones supporters already selected, we calculate the conditional probability that the $(n+1)$-th person favors Jones. The two cases arise from here is that:
- Case 1: $x$ Jones supporters selected
If $x$ Jones supporters have been selected in the first $n$ draws, then there are $m-x$ Jones supporters remaining out of the $N-n$ remaining voters. The conditional probability that the $(n+1)$-th person favors Jones, given that $x$ Jones supporters have been selected is $$P((n+1)-th \ person \ favors \ Jones \ | \ x \ Jones \ supporters \ selected) = \frac{m-x}{N-n}$$
- Case 2: $n-x$ Jones non-supporters selected
If $n-x$ Jones non-supporters have been selected, there are still $m$ Jones supporters left and the number of remaining voters is $N-n$. The conditional probability that the $(n+1)$-th person favors Jones in this case is$$P((n+1)-th \ person \ favors \ Jones \ | \ x \ Jones \ non \ supporters \ selected) = \frac{m}{N-n}$$
The unconditional probability that the $(n+1)$-th person favors Jones is just the sum of all possible cases. We sum over the probabilities for each possible $x$ weighted by the probability of selecting exactly $x$ Jones supporters.
$$P((n+1)-th \ person \ favors \ Jones) = \sum_{x=0}^{n} P(x \ Jones \ supporters \ selected) \cdot P((n+1)-th \ person \ favors \ Jones \ | \ x \ Jones \ supporters \ selected)$$
From this we observe that the overall ratio of Jones supporters to the total population stays the same - meaning that the ratio $\frac{m}{N}$ remains valid at each step.
Please ignore the horrendous notation, but a proof similar to this would be valid I believe.

I understand the idea behind your answer. But are your cases comprehensive? And how do you show that the last expression gives the same ratio as before? Because you have put in an induction framework, but your induction step seems to not justify why it is correct.
